# elem.nodeName returns undefined, bug in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, validation

Currently, I'm adapting a registration page to use Ajax/jQuery.  Its in the simple stage, asking simply for a username and password.

I want to use jQuery to tell the user if the current entry in the username textbox is invalid or has already been taken.  If either conditional is met, the div namemsg will have text added to it and execute the fadeIn event.

The page loads with he submit button disabled, and upon passing validation the button is enabled.  To do this, I have the following ajax request to handle the username validation

```
$("#username").keyup(function(){
    //get current value
    thisVal = $(this).val();

    //execute request to see if current val exists in database
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "includes/phpscripts.php?action=checkUser",
      data: {username:thisVal},
      success: function(data){

        //if username is already taken, show warning and disable submit button
        if (data == 'true'){
          $("#namemsg").text("Username is already taken");
          $("#namemsg").fadeIn(100);
          $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } 

        //otherwise, possible valid username
        else if (data == 'false'){

          //check if username is of the proper length.  If not, display
          //error and disable submit button
          if ($(this).val().length < 5){
            $("#namemsg").text("Invalid Username");
            $("#namemsg").fadeIn(100);
            $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          } 


          //valid username, enable submit button and hide any error messages
          else {
            $("#namemsg").hide();
            $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
          }

        }
      }

    });

    return false;
});
```

My issue is that the request gets the propper value from the server, but firebug complains that `elem.nodeName` is undefined at line 2368 of jquery 1.7.2.  That line is

```
if ( elem ) {
  hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ];
```

When I set the breakpoint at `if (elem)`, `elem` had the values

```
nodeName : INPUT
type : text
```

and `hooks` returned undefined.  Is this a Firefox specific issue, an issue with my code or jQuery?  Also, Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your `success` handler, `this` is the jqXHR request, not the `$("#username")` field, so `$(this).val()` is erroring.

As you've got the value cached, it'd be best to use `thisVal` instead of `$(this).val()`, but in general the way to fix this is to set the `context` option to the element;

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
    type: 'GET',
    // etc
});
```

You can see the docs for this method on the [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) page (search for "context").

And another way you'll see is to set the `this` that pointed to the element to another variable;

```
$("#username").keyup(function(){
    var that = this;

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "includes/phpscripts.php?action=checkUser",
      data: {username:thisVal},
      success: function(data){
          // use `that` and `$(that)` in here
      }    
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the help!  I've gotten so used to implied parameters for functions that it never occurred to me that the values were out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line

```
if ($(this).val().length < 5){
```

`this` doesn't refer to the `#username` inside that async callback.

Use

```
if (thisVal.length < 5){
```

As you cached that earlier.